# Set host IP when creating Docker network

Tags: docker

When creating a bridge network with `docker network create`, is there an option to specify the IP address of the Docker host?

I’ve tried the `gateway` option, but that doesn’t seem to be it.

`docker.host.internal` will resolve to the host IP, but can it be specified when creating a network or running a container?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve? Using `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` sets the address of `host.docker.internal` to *an* address of the host, but not necessarily the bridge address for your network. In most cases this is just fine. If you really need the bridge address, you can use the default route visible inside the container (`ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}'`).

Comment: I need to give a DNS server some mock A records with an IP that points to the Docker host. It's part of a CI setup that needs to run a particular DNS server for testing purposes

Comment: Basically what I need is that any DNS query will resolve to the IP address of the Docker host